# Render 10 000 links on same page

Tags: html, memory, rendering

I need to display about 10000 links on a same 'visible' page.

By 'visible' i mean the document can be spliced with differents iframes or other techniques but has to show on the same browser window. The layout is not the problem has i can css{display:block;float:left;width=1;height=1} show em all in a quite small area.

My problem is that i could not display more than 2000 links before the browser slows to unacceptable speed .. then crashed.

My first attempt was the simpliest, map-area to void high DOM magnitude.

I tried with ajax calls, javascript differed appending, plain html, **mapArea** and nothing works.

I tested with what i believe to be an average short-link, like so :

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/?fake-parameter=longer-url" title="Fake text to sumulate about 35 characters" target="_blank">Fake text to sumulate about 35 characters</a>
```

> Nota (tiny complaint of mine): it's hard to search for this specific
>   technical point, all search results treat about SEO and what Matt
>   Cutts wrote about SEO and what Google pointed about SEO or what more
>   than 100 links will ruin my page ranking.

Comment: Pagination is not an option here? I mean 10'000 links is **A LOT**

Comment: I don't want to be the one who'll have to scroll through the page to find the link I want :)

Comment: Can you Ajax load more and more as you scroll ? Maybe hide what is not in view, i mean you cant possible display all 10k at the same time? Otherwise 10k does not seem possible.

Comment: I am about to suggest planet earth to buy 16-cores x 4 with 1 terrabyte memory computers .. but it not an issue .. yet.

Comment: How are you actually displaying these links?  If a user is scrolling through and the magnitude of the DOM is too high, perhaps you can remove non-visible links and re-add them if the user scrolls back to that point?

Comment: @David I tried with a rooted image map-area. All tested with <body> first child.

Answer (score 1):

With out knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve its hard to advise and just to echo what others have said 10,000 links on a page seems like far to many - what are your reasons?

Also I can see this would have some consequences with seo.

Three possibilities I would consider:

1. **Using pagination** to limit the results to a sensible amount per page with  the standard page 1 /2 / 3 previous / next buttons etc PHP example - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/
2. **Using some form of ajax auto complete /  suggest**  This would then only load subsections of your results at a time - http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/auto-completion-scripts/
3. **jQuery plug in** (Que the haters ;-) - Or use something that uses both ajax and pagination such as this (random pick from google) table sorter plugin that can apparently handle large data sets - http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Dynamic-Data-Grid-Plugin-appendGrid.html

PS IFrames are typically not recommend these days so I would try and avoid these if possible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand your problem. I just added 10000 links on a page made them float:left and 1px big and it works nicely with Firefox 23. I have put the example on

[Example with 10000 links](http://franzherbert.at/test_many_links.html)

Of course the rendering takes some time, but it does not crash at all. Which browser does crash and how fast shall this document load and render?

Comment: Franz ? AlvalHenrik, thanks for your effort. What happens is that, yes, i am able to see the source and all the links, but the browser jams out of memory. I see CPU usage raise to 80% system when i hover the links.

Comment: What browser are you using? And do you need to generate the links dynamically or do you use a static HTML.

Comment: Like explained in the question, i just need to 'display' them in the same page, no matter what technique i can use. For my browser, it's a front-end development station. I am testing in virtual with latest versions -2 (without plugins) for firefox, opera, gChrome, IE, Safari-pc. On standard mode i test with all latest versions (with plugins).